# Retrieve multiple GET parameters with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I try to retrieve multiple GET parameters with Express, but req.params is always empty. I am not entirely sure how to do it properly with Express 4 as the answers vary a lot because there has changed a lot with newer releases of Express/Node.js I guess.

**This is my URL call:**

```
http://localhost:3000/accounts/players?term=asddsa&_type=query&q=asddsa
```

The http status code is actually 200 so this address actually exists.

**This is my router:**

```
router.get('/players', function(req, res) {
    var searchTerm = req.term;
    console.log("Term: " + JSON.stringify(req.params));
    res.json({"result": "Account deleted"});
});
```

Console log output is:

```
Term: {}
```

**I have tried different things such as:**

```
router.get('/players/:term/:_type/:q', function(req, res) {
```

But this caused a 404 for the GET request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter the url parameters after the '?' as you did - the parameters will be under `req.query` rather than `req.params`, like so:

```
router.get('/players', function(req, res) {
    var searchTerm = req.term;
    console.log("Term: " + JSON.stringify(req.query));
    res.json({"result": "Account deleted"});
});
```

If you want to use params instead - your url should look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/accounts/players/asddsa/query/asddsa
```

And the router function can be written as you tried:

```
router.get('/players/:term/:_type/:q', function(req, res) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation, helped a lot to sort my confusion about other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
router.get('/players', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.query) // should return the query string

    var searchTerm = req.term;
    console.log("Term: " + JSON.stringify(req.params));
    res.json({"result": "Account deleted"});
});
```